# Dojo Horizontal Slider - A tooltip to hover over the slider handle with current slider value?

Tags: dojo

I have just started with Dojo widgets. Recently, I did this [Dijit Horizontal Slider Sample](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dijit/form/HorizontalSlider.html#programmatic-example-of-a-horizontal-slider),and I have been wondering how to make a tooltip follow the slider handle with the current slider value as the tooltip content.

I have tried the same but am facing two issues:

One, the tooltip appears at the end of the slider rather than constantly hovering on the slider handle.

Two, the tooltip displays a value only when I stop sliding rather than changing seamlessly.

How to overcome these?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the tooltip to move with the slider, you have to find a way to open it from the slider handle, not from the entire horizontal slider widget.  I do not know if the actual slider you move with the mouse is it's own widget or not.  From the declarative sample online the HTML for the handle looks like this

```
<div data-dojo-attach-point="sliderHandle,focusNode" class="dijitSliderImageHandle dijitSliderImageHandleH" data-dojo-attach-event="press:_onHandleClick" role="slider" aria-valuemin="-10" aria-valuemax="10" tabindex="0" aria-valuenow="4" style="position: absolute;"></div>
```

So you can try something like the following, if you can get a reference to the sliderHandle object.

```
/*
 * Create the tooltip dialog that you want to show (I use tooltip dialog, 
 * but you can do the same with basic tooltip)
 */ 
var myTooltipDialogbase = new ttdialog({
    id: 'myTooltipDialogBase',
    style: "width: 275px;"
});
```

Then in your event handler (in this example right mouse click) you open the popup

```
        /**
         * On right mouse click, opens the tooltip dialog
         */
        on(sliderHandle, 'contextmenu', function (event) {

            popup.open({
                parent: sliderHandle,
                popup: myTooltipDialogbase,
                around: sliderHandle.domNode
            });

        });
```

**EDIT**:
For your second question, you can use the slider property onChange() to do something each time the value of the slider changes. You must set intermediateChanges=true so onChange is called when sliding.  In your case, in onChange(), if you can get a reference to the tooltip, then change the value of one of the tooltip objects for every value change of the slider.

Comment: Thanks... I'm going to try that out.

Comment: A quick question if you don't mind, the textbox value is constantly being updated by just setting the value without Stateful. Why so?

Comment: @ShyProgrammer Oh sorry didn't see that example, see the edit in my post.